# Pytorch model weight type conversion

Tags: pytorch

I'm trying to do inference on FlowNet2-C model loading from file.
However, I met some data type problem.  How can I resolve it?

- [Source code](https://github.com/HTLife/FlowNetTest)
- [FlowNet2-C pre-trained model](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1BFT6b7KgKJC8rA59RmOVAXRM_S7aSfKE/view?usp=sharing)

$ python main.py

```
Initializing Datasets
  [0.000s] Loading checkpoint '/notebooks/data/model/FlowNet2-C_checkpoint.pth.tar'
  [1.293s] Loaded checkpoint '/notebooks/data/model/FlowNet2-C_checkpoint.pth.tar' (at epoch 0)
(1L, 6L, 384L, 512L)
<class 'torch.autograd.variable.Variable'>
  [1.642s] Operation failed


Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 102, in <module>
    main()
  File "main.py", line 98, in main
    summary(input_size, model)
  File "main.py", line 61, in summary
    model(x)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 357, in __call__
    result = self.forward(*input, **kwargs)
  File "/notebooks/data/vinet/FlowNetC.py", line 75, in forward
    out_conv1a = self.conv1(x1)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 357, in __call__
    result = self.forward(*input, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/torch/nn/modules/container.py", line 67, in forward
    input = module(input)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 357, in __call__
    result = self.forward(*input, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/torch/nn/modules/conv.py", line 282, in forward
    self.padding, self.dilation, self.groups)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/torch/nn/functional.py", line 90, in conv2d
    return f(input, weight, bias)
RuntimeError: Input type (CUDAFloatTensor) and weight type (CPUFloatTensor) should be the same
```

Comment: the links give 404 error

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Maybe that is because your `model` and input `x` to the model has different data types. It seems that the model parameters have been moved to GPU, but your input `x` is on GPU.

You can try to use `model.cuda()` after line 94, which will put the model on the GPU. Then the error should disappear.

Comment: It works like a charm!  What's the difference between setting GPU at th.load and `model.cuda()` ?

Comment: I usually initialize the model, then load the state dict, then initialize the model from the state dict and move the model to GPU. I think it is the canonical way to do model loading.